# What package is userInput located in?

Tags: java

Which package is `userInput` located in?

```
Scanner userInput;
for (char c : userInput.toCharArray()) {
}
```

The compile time exception I get is `.toCharArray is undefined for the Scanner type.`

Comment: what exactly are you trying to ask ?

Comment: What do you mean by userInput? are you looking for a specific class? a method for getting user input?

Comment: What's userInput? Sounds like a variable name.

Comment: Are you looking for `System.in`

Comment: Sorry I shouldve been more specific. I'm writing code for an array; for (char c : userInput.toCharArray())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [java.util.Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for input.  You would create an instance like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

`System.in` is an [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html). This means you could also use it's `read` methods to read from it, but that is usually a harder way to read user input.

But, Scanner is **not** the user input; it is a class to help you read user input. Nor does it have a method `toCharArray()`.
You use Scanner's [readline](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) method to get an input String, and the String returned has a `toCharArray()` method.

Comment: You're welcome. I'd like to suggest that next time, you try to make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) of your problem. Or in this case, a code snippet that shows how your compilation fails. Questions that show effort are generally better received.